# How can I make sure a "pool" bean gets all the other beans it needs?

Tags: spring, postconstruct

I have a spring config where I define hundreds of actions which extend `MyAction`. I have a pool where an execution service can look up actions. I can't use the appContext directly because each action has one or more "keys" which the execution service will use and pool cuts that dependency.

So the pool must be able to collect all beans of type `MyAction` (or rather beans that extend `MyAction`).

The method `ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType()` seems to do what I need but when can I safely call it?

It would be great if I could call it in a `@PostConstruct` method but is it guaranteed that the bean factory has seen added each and every bean from the config at that time?

Note: Almost all of my beans are `@Lazy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use injection by constructor and passing a `Collection` of yours `MyAction`

Something like

```
 @Component
 public class Foo {
     private final Set<MyAction> myActions;

     @Inject
     public Foo(Set<MyAction> myActions) { this.myActions = myActions; }
 }
```

or

```
 public class Foo {
     private Set<MyAction> myActions;

     @Inject
     public void setMyActions(Set<MyAction> myActions) { this.myActions = myActions; }
 }
```

Spring will take care of creating the set with all beans that extends `MyAction`.

In the first case, they are injected by constructor, you can safely use them in any method.

In the second case, Spring will eventually call the setter. You can either do any post processing in the setter or add a `@PostConstruct` method that works on `myActions`.

Comment: This looks promising. Let me write a test case.

Comment: Is there a way to create this bean without doing a component scan?

Comment: @AaronDigulla You say `Foo`? You can "create it" via xml and still using the `@Inject` or `@Autowired` annotation for your constructor.

You will still be needing to scan classes with `MyAction` or declare them in the XML.

Another requirement (that you need for `@PostConstruct` also) is activating the annotation-config scan like 

    <context:annotation-config />

at your XML.

Comment: You're welcome. Note: I like to avoid using XML based configurations. It would be nice when a bean method in a `@Configuration` could return a type and Spring would do the `new` for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ListableBeanFactory` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799316/how-to-collect-and-inject-all-beans-of-a-given-type-in-spring-xml-configuration). Also [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html) is API documentation. Method [getBeansOfType](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType%28java.lang.Class,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) has parameter `allowEagerInit` which forces eager init of lazy object.

Comment: Will `allowEagerInit` create all beans or only beans with the type `MyAction`?

Comment: It probably will create all beans to check their types. Definitely it will create beans which are instantiated with factory methods.