# got declared spring beans in an other spring bean

Tags: java, spring

```
@Component
public class IServiceCollection {
  @Resource
  private IService service1;
  @Resource
  private IService service2;
  @Resource
  private IService service3;
  @Resource
  private IService service4;
  @Resource
  private IService service5;

  public List<IService> getAllServices(){
    List<IService>  iServiceList =  new ArrayList<IService>();

    iServiceList.add(service1);
    iServiceList.add(service2);
    return iServiceList;
  }
}
```

in `IServiceCollection` I will refer lots of `IService` beans like `service1`, `servvice2`, etc.  I wanna get all of the service beans in method `getAllServices()`.

How can I add all the services to the list automatically, not like the code above?

Comment: look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2799467/1066779)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

.1. If you inject in a map this way:

```
@Component
public class IServiceCollection {
  @Autowired
  private Map<String, IService> services;
```

that would inject in all implementations of IService with the key of the map being the bean name

.2. You can inject in a list this way:

```
@Component
public class IServiceCollection {

  @Autowired
  private List<IService> services;
```

again you would have a list of IService instances.